# useState not updating array right away

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a shopping cart app and I want to prevent an item from appearing on the cart page twice if there's a duplicate. I'm trying to check an array of items objects from the useState hook. If the array contains an object with the item name, I want to prevent it from being added twice, otherwise I want to push it into the array. But when I console log the array, it doesn't update right away. Also, after I hit the "addItemToCart" button on ProductsDetails.jsx twice, I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined." Sorry if I'm not explaining it clearly. Here's my code. Any help would be appreciated.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  const [cartCount, setCartCount] = useState(0);
  const [cartTotal, setCartTotal] = useState(0.00);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavigationBar count={cartCount} />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path="/products" component={ProductsPage} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" component={ProfilePage} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/cart"
            render={() => {
              return (
                <CartPage
                  setCartCount={setCartCount}
                  cartItems={cartItems}
                  cartTotal={cartTotal}
                  cartCount={cartCount}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/:details"
            render={() => (
              <ProductDetails
                cartItems={cartItems}
                setCartItems={setCartItems}
                setCartCount={setCartCount}
                setCartTotal={setCartTotal}
              />
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ProductsDetails.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import "./ProductDetails.css";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const ProductDetails = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
  const productInfo = products.find(
    (item) => item.name === location.state.name
  );
  const { name, image, price } = productInfo;

  const cartCounter = (counter) => {
    props.setCartCount((counter += 1));
  };

  const cartPriceCounter = (counter) => {
    props.setCartTotal((counter += price));
  };

  const addItemToCart = () => {

    const product = {
      name,
      price,
    };

    if(!props.cartItems.find(e => e.name === product.name)){
      props.setCartItems([...props.cartItems, product]);
    }

   console.log(props.cartItems)
  };



  return (
    <div className="details-container">
      <div className="details-card">
        <img className="details-img" src={image} alt={name} />
        <div className="details-div">
          <h3 className="details-title">{name}</h3>
          <p className="details-price">${price}</p>
          <button
            className="add-to-cart"
            onClick={() => {
              props.setCartCount(cartCounter);
              props.setCartTotal(cartPriceCounter);
              props.setCartItems(addItemToCart);
            }}
          >
            Add To Cart
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

Comment: instead of `props.setCartItems(addItemToCart);`, just call `addItemToCart()`

Comment: Have you tried checking if the `localStorage.getItem("data")` really gives data? I suspect that's where the problem comes from

Comment: And also you should use `useEffect` function to consolse log the new values for cartItems. If you just console log it directly after you use the setState function it can't guarantee that it will show the new value.

Comment: It should never show the new value if logging directly after, if it does it indicates you've mutated state.

Answer (score 1):

The mutated state won't be reflected in the same render(i.e. in console.log), it would be updated when the next render occurs due to state change
See https://medium.com/ableneo/react-setstate-does-not-immediately-update-the-state-84dbd26f67d5

You could use setState with function argument which would have the updated value.